# Put last element of each column in quotation marks

Tags: regex, csv, perl, replace

I am trying to put every last element of each column of a csv into quotation marks by using regex in Visual Studio Code.
 I am matching the string using `[^,;]+$` and trying to replace it by using `"$1"`.
After replacing, the strings are not in order anymore and some vanish.
Can anybody help me out here?

My csv is shaped like this:

```
SOME_ID,SOME_ID2,SOME_ID3,NUM,CODE
1234,100,1723,1,403
1235,101,1723,2,486
1236,101,1723,3,5822
```

Comment: You forgot the group - `([^,;]+)$`. Or, instead of group 1, refer to the whole match, `"$&"`

Comment: thank you that solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer to capture you require to put the expression in a capture group `(...)`

Your regex is correct and simply needs to be put in the capturing group, `([^,]+)$` , should fix your search and replace.

As Wiktor suggested in the comments `$&` will refer to the whole match and that can also be used.